# How to find out tags like [FNAME] in content field in php?

Tags: php, fckeditor, yii

I have taken field name **content** in my form in that I have used fckeditor.

in content field If i am entering like

eg: "Please add [FNAME] and Roll no [ROLLNO]"

and in place of the `FNAME` and `ROLLNO` the value should be come from db

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Have you looked at any of the string replacement methods for PHP? str_replace and so forth?

Comment: $body = preg_replace('/\[FNAME]/',$name,$body); <br/> but i have $str="Please add [FNAME] and Roll no [ROLLNO]";<br/> I have to find out [FNAME] and [ROLLNO].and it should be replace

Comment: You don't need a regex for this. Simply call this method - http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $content  = "Please add [FNAME] and Roll no [CONTACT_NO].....[here][EMAIL]";    
  $find     = array("[CONTACT_NO]"=>$contact_no,"[FNAME]"=>$name,"[EMAIL]"=>$email); 
  $newstr   = strtr($content, $find); 
  $body  = str_replace($content,$newstr,$body);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native PHP function [`strtr`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to do this.

> strtr — Translate characters or replace substrings

Comment: $find=array("[CONTACT_NO]"=>$contact_no,"[FNAME]"=>$name,"[EMAIL]"=>$email);  <br/>$newstr=strtr($content, $find);  $body   =str_replace($content,$newstr,$body);